# Pyro and file sequencing

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, pyro, msp

When I add new files through patch it messes up File Sequence table and at the same time the size of the patch becomes the same as the size of the product installation. I'm using PatchGroup element to overcome this behavior but as the number of new files added through the patch grows it becomes hard to keep track of the last used number in PatchGroup. I found this post bu Rob Mensching:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/how-to-control-File-Sequence-no-in-WIX-td5933489.html#a5934096

If I understand it correctly pyro should automatically add new files to the File Sequence end. Am I doing something wrong or pyro isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

In WiX v3.5 and v3.6 file sequencing should just be handled for you using pyro and the Patch element. WiX v3.0 things were a bit more touchy and PatchCreation element never did things for you automatically. PatchGroup shouldn't be needed using the newest tools.